# Extract values from string containing xml in silverlight

Tags: xml, silverlight

```
string xmlText= "
                  <Person>
                     <Name>abc</Name>
                     <Age>22</Age>
                  </person>";
```

i want the values abc and 22
m using silverlight 4 and XmlTextReader is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse XML data in Silverlight by using either LINQ to XML or [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(VS.95).aspx).

Here's some example code that uses XmlReader. It's very simple and *only* works with the exact input string that you defined. But, it should be enough to get you on your way.

```
string xmlText= @"
                  <Person>
                    <Name>abc</Name>
                      <Age>22</Age>
                  </Person>";
// Create an XmlReader
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlText)))
{
  // Parse the file and display each of the nodes.
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    if (reader.Name == "Name" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      // Advace to the element's text node
      reader.Read();
      // ... do what you want (you can get the value with reader.Value)
    }
    else if (reader.Name == "Age" && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
    {
      // Advace to the element's text node
      reader.Read();
      // ... do what you want (you can get the value with reader.Value)
    }
}
```

Here's an article with more details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc188996(VS.95).aspx